# Code equivalent to the 'let' keyword in chained LINQ extension method calls

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, linq-to-objects

Using the C# compilers query comprehension features, you can write code like:

```
var names = new string[] { "Dog", "Cat", "Giraffe", "Monkey", "Tortoise" };
var result =
    from animalName in names
    let nameLength = animalName.Length
    where nameLength > 3
    orderby nameLength
    select animalName;
```

In the query expression above, the `let` keyword allows a value to be passed forward to the where and orderby operations without duplicate calls to `animalName.Length`.

What is the equivalent set of LINQ extension method calls that achieves what the "let" keyword does here?

Comment: FYI, the C# 3.0 specification explains every query comprehension translation rule in excruciating detail.

Comment: and for those who find the spec heavy going, Jon Skeet's C# in Depth covers it too ;-p

Comment: The C# Language Specifications are downloadable Word documents whose content is not indexed by search engines and is neither linkable nor browseable online. It would be a great help if the specifications were available online.

Answer (score 283, accepted):

Let doesn't have its own operation; it piggy-backs off of `Select`. You can see this if you use "reflector" to pull apart an existing dll.

it will be *something* like:

```
var result = names
        .Select(animalName => new { nameLength = animalName.Length, animalName})
        .Where(x=>x.nameLength > 3)
        .OrderBy(x=>x.nameLength)
        .Select(x=>x.animalName);
```

Comment: You can also use the little "lambda" button in the result pane of LinqPad to see the generated code *if* you start with a Queryable. In other words, if you change your first line to var names = new string [] { "Dog", ... }.AsQueryable(); then run the whole thing in LinqPad, click the little lambda button, you will see generated code virtually identical to Marc's answer.

Comment: I needed to use the `.Dump()` extension method in LinqPad to see the resulting lambda.

Answer (score 100):

There's a good article [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20091003125950/http://gregbeech.com/blogs/tech/archive/2008/04/21/translating-c-3-0-query-syntax-for-linq-to-objects-part-4-let.aspx)

Essentially `let` creates an anonymous tuple. It's equivalent to:

```
var result = names.Select(
  animal => new { animal = animal, nameLength = animal.Length })
.Where(x => x.nameLength > 3)
.OrderBy(y => y.nameLength)
.Select(z => z.animal);
```

Comment: I quote the article above `it seems prudent to recommend against using the let keyword in cases where you do not need to transform a variable`

Comment: I quote it further: `This could be considered a micro-optimisation`

Answer (score 7):

There is also a .Let extension method in System.Interactive, but its purpose is to introduce a lambda expression to be evaluated 'in-line' in a fluent expression. For instance, consider (in LinqPad, say) the following expression that creates new random numbers every time it's executed:

```
var seq = EnumerableEx.Generate(
    new Random(),
    _ => true,
    _ => _,
    x => x.Next());
```

To see that new random samples show up every time, consider the following

```
seq.Zip(seq, Tuple.Create).Take(3).Dump();
```

which produces pairs in which the left and right are different. To produce pairs in which the left and right are always the same, do something like the following:

```
seq.Take(3).ToList().Let(xs => xs.Zip(xs, Tuple.Create)).Dump();
```

If we could invoke lambda expressions directly, we might write

```
(xs => xs.Zip(xs, Tuple.Create))(seq.Take(3).ToList()).Dump();
```

But we can't invoke lambda expressions as if they were methods.

Answer (score 1):

about [Code equivalent to the 'let' keyword in chained LINQ extension method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092687/code-equivalent-to-the-let-keyword-in-chained-linq-extension-method-calls#comment51041780_1092732)

above comment is no more valid

```
var x = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }.AsQueryable();
(from val in x
let val1 = val
let val2 = val + 1
where val2 > val1
select val
).Dump();
```

produces

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
.Select(
  val =>
     new
     {
         val = val,
         val1 = val
     }
)
.Select(
  temp0 =>
     new
     {
         temp0 = temp0,
         val2 = (temp0.val + 1)
     }
)
.Where(temp1 => (temp1.val2 > temp1.temp0.val1))
.Select(temp1 => temp1.temp0.val)
```

so multiple `let` are optimized now