# Difference between Select and Where in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

What is the difference between `.Select()` and `.Where()` in Entity Framework?
Eg

```
return ContextSet().Select(x=> x.FirstName == "John")
```

vs

```
ContextSet().Where(x=> x.FirstName == "John")
```

When should I use `.Select` vs `.Where`?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: It can occasionally be useful; I've written that once or twice.

Comment: You're looking for the documentation.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Linq: What is the difference between Select and Where](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212746) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq: What is the difference between Select and Where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212746/linq-what-is-the-difference-between-select-and-where)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

[`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) is a projection, so what you get is the expression `x=> x.FirstName == "John"` evaluated for each element in `ContextSet()` on the server. i.e. lots of true/false values (the same number as your original list). If you look the select will return something like `IEnumerable<bool>` (because the type of `x=> x.FirstName == "John"` is a bool).

[`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) filters the results, returning an enumerable of the original type (no projection).

---

So, use `Select` when you want to keep all results, but change their type (project them).

Use `Where` when you want to filter your results, keeping the original type

Comment: So where is more like the sql select statement?

Comment: No, WHERE in LINQ and SQL is used to filter the results, and SELECT projects the results in both LINQ and SQL

Comment: The SELECT statement controls what gets returned for each result data row, did example you could have a firstname and lastname field and have the select change it to fullname = firstname + " " + lastname, so the data you queried had 2 fields but the results of the query had 1.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out.  I just don't know why people keep using words like "projection" when they could just use more simple and direct phrases like "controls what gets returned" or even "allows the developer to choose which columns are returned".  I didn't even know "projection" was a part of the developer lexicon much less what it meant in this context.  "pick your columns [or class properties]" does.

Comment: @Jeremy projection is a term from database theory. But I agree it is not as common as other ways of explaining what SELECT does.

Answer (score 31):

`Where()` is a filter.

`Select()` selects a different piece of data.
Your `Select()` example will return a collection of booleans.