# difference between select and where in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq: What is the difference between Select and Where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212746/linq-what-is-the-difference-between-select-and-where)

What's the difference between

```
var a = Doc.Document.Where(n => n.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
```

and

```
var b = Doc.Document.Select(n => n.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
```

**Why variable b is a boolean ?**

Sorry about my ignorance, I am new to LINQ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.  So in the first example you are selecting elements from your list where the function `n.Id == id` is true.

[Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) Projects each element of a sequence into a new form, so in your second example you get a list of booleans which is the result of the function `n.Id == id` on each element.

Comment: > Thanks a lot.
I understand better now.