# using CopyToDataTable with ienumerable select

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have a `DataTable` which I am filtering by converting it to `Enumerable` as

```
_dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(s) s.Field(Of String)("LF").Trim().Contains(sFilter)).Take(25).Cast(Of DataRow).CopyToDataTable()
```

I am getting exception while execution as `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.` Where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select Booleans as a result of the function. Try Using Where instead of select.

Comment: I'm guessing someone could post a better answer expalining the difference between selecting and filtering. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212746/linq-what-is-the-difference-between-select-and-where

Comment: Or you can edit the same with details. But this solve my issue.