# How to select all objects that have a property value in list of values?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table named Items. Items have a property named "locationId" Given a list of location Ids, how do I select all items?

List example

```
List<long> locationIds = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Essentially the query below, but for multiple locations at once:

```
var sleectedItems= db.Items.Select(i => i.LocationId == 2);
```

Comment: Linq's `Select()` is for projection, not filtering. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1212782

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `Where` with `Contains`:

```
var selectedItems = db.Items.Where(x => locationIds.Contains(x.LocationId));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, any idea what I am doing wrong? http://i.imgur.com/VY1RkK8.png

Comment: What is the type of `LocationId`?

Comment: It's "long" in entity, big int in the db.

Comment: The error message implies that it's not `long`. Maybe it's `long?` (`Nullable`)?

Comment: That was my understanding of the error as well. It's a long though: "        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }" - this is from the model definition. I will come back and accept your answer once I figure it out. I am sure it SHOULD work, I just don't know why it doesn't for me.

Comment: You showed the property definition of `Id`, we're talking about `LocationId`.

Comment: You were right - it was long?. Sorry, I was working 12+ hours straight at that point, so I was a bit out of it. Thank you very, very much.