# Return List<object> from IEnumerable C#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a method:

```
public List<AxeResult> LoadAxes(string kilometriczone, string axe)
{
    IEnumerable<AxeResult> allAxes = PullAxes();
    var findAxes = allAxes.Select(a => a.KilometricZone.StartsWith(kilometriczone) || a.KilometricZone.StartsWith(axe));

    return findAxes.Cast<AxeResult>().ToList();
}
```

I have this error:

> `IEnumerable<bool>` does not contain a definition for `ToList` and
>   the best extension method overload `Enumerable.ToList<AxeResult>` (
>   `IEnumerable<AxeResult>`) requires a receptor type `IEnumerable<AxeResult>`

I want to return a List of AxeResult after the search operation.

Comment: You use `Select` with `StartsWith`, which returns a `bool`. Maybe you want to use a where statement instead?

Comment: That error message is odd.  I would have expected a run time `InvalidCastException`  about not being able to cast `bool` to `AxeResult`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is to filter the collection. That's what [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) is for:

```
public List<AxeResult> LoadAxes(string kilometriczone, string axe)
{
    return PullAxes()
        .Where(a => a.KilometricZone.StartsWith(kilometriczone) || 
                    a.KilometricZone.StartsWith(axe))
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some explanation in addition to the given answers:

**Where()** method acts like a **filter** and returns **a subset of the same set**

**Select()** method makes **projection** and returns **new set**

There is comprehensive explanation about the diffrence between .Select() and Where() methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212746/linq-what-is-the-difference-between-select-and-where).