# LINQ - most efficent way to filter and sort by same function

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I'm looking for an efficient way to sort a collection by a function, and at the same time filter the collection based on the evaluation of said function.  To illustrate:

```
var materialsByExpiry = from m in materials
                        where m.ExpiryDate() >= today
                        orderby m.ExpiryDate()
                        select m;
```

Since `materials` is a large collection, and `ExpiryDate` is a non-trivial calculation, I'd like to minimise the number of calls to `ExpiryDate`.  Clearly `ExpiryDate` needs to be called only once for each material, but this code calls it *n* + *q* times, where *n* is the total number of elements and *q* is the number passing the filter.

I can see that one possibility would be define a struct that stores materials along with their expiry dates and work with that.  But is there a more efficient way (short of spending the time working out my own sort/filter algorithm)?

Comment: If you're selecting `m` from the `materials` why need an `orderby`? If `ExpiryDate` needs to be calculated only once, is it better to run a separate loop, calculate and update a property before the linq?

Comment: Why not hang a lazy evaluator (Lazy<T>) on the ExpiryDate function? Calculate it the first time and return the same value there after.

Comment: is there a reason why you calculate the `ExpiryDate` dynamically? can it change during runtime?

Comment: @MongZhu It's the way the system works.  `materials` comes from outside of the code I'm writing, and I need to call a method of its class to extract the value we're sorting/filtering by.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [let](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause) keyword to temporarily save the value which is returned by `ExpiryDate()`

```
var materialsByExpiry = from m in materials
                        let date = m.ExpiryDate() 
                        where date >= today
                        orderby date
                        select m;
```

This will reduce the number of calls down to the ones needed for the `Where` clause.

Here is an example for LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{   
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;  
    List<Material> materials = new List<UserQuery.Material>();

    materials.Add(new Material { Hours = 6 });
    materials.Add(new Material { Hours = 2 });
    materials.Add(new Material { Hours = -6 });
    materials.Add(new Material { Hours = -6 });
    materials.Add(new Material { Hours = 4 });

    // normal version
    var materialsByExpiry = (from m in materials
                            where m.ExpiryDate() >= today
                            orderby m.ExpiryDate()
                            select m).ToList();

    Material.count.Dump("COUNT normal");
    Material.count = 0;

    // LET version
    var materialsByExpiry_Let = (from m in materials
                            let date = m.ExpiryDate() 
                            where date >= today
                            orderby date
                            select m).ToList();

    Material.count.Dump("COUNT using LET");
    materialsByExpiry.Dump();
    materialsByExpiry_Let.Dump();
}

public class Material
{
    public static int count = 0;
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate()
    {
        count++;
        return DateTime.Now.AddHours(Hours);
    }
}
```

And here is the comparative output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  `let` is simple, straightforward, and speeds things up a bit.

I'm made to wonder what it looks like in desugared form (written as LINQ method calls rather than the fancy LINQ syntax).  I don't see a Let method in System.Linq.

Comment: @Stewart you're welcome. I guess it looks in lambda [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240420/5174469) not so fancy ;) It also looks like it would iterate 1 time too much over the entire collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a generic extension method that invokes the computationally intensive method, and stores the output in a [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) along with the object itself.

```
public static IEnumerable<(TSource Item, TProperty1 Property1)>
    Precompute<TSource, TProperty1>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TProperty1> property1Selector)
{
    return source.Select(item => (item, property1Selector(item)));
}
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
var materialsByExpiry = from m in materials.Precompute(m => m.ExpiryDate())
                        where m.Property1 >= today
                        orderby m.Property1
                        select m.Item;
```

The naming is awkward though. You can't give meaningful names to the properties of the tuple this way.