# Using Let in Lambda Expression while querying from a datatable

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a data table and I need to convert the contents of that data table to a class List and I used Linq for that.It worked well.But I was asked to convert that linq query to Lambda Expression and there I had a Little trouble while using Let.I will the sample code.

Working linq query:

```
var NewUser = (from dt in dsMappedDataFields.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
               let tempDetails = dt.Field<string>("Name") == "Rojer" ? "NW" : "India"
               let tempNumber = tempDetails == "India" ? "918956" : "0456"
               select new User
                        {
                           Name = dt.Field<string>("Name"),
                           Age = dt.Field<int>("Age"),
                           Details = tempDetails,
                           Number = tempNumber
                        }).ToList();
```

Lambda expression:

```
var User = dsMappedDataFields.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().

                             Select(dr =>
                                 new User
                                 {
                                     Name = dr.Field<string>("Name"),
                                     Age = dr.Field<int>("Age"),
                                     Details = dr.Field<string>("Details"),
                                     Number = dr.Field<string>("Number")
                                 }).ToList();
```

As you can see I have to check some conditions before converting the data to list which I have done earlier.. Please do help me with solving this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092687/code-equivalent-to-the-let-keyword-in-chained-linq-extension-method-calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lambda you pass to `Select` can have a block, so you can add any kind of code there:

```
var User = dsMappedDataFields.Tables[0].Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(dr =>
    {
        var tempDetails = dt.Field<string>("Name") == "Rojer" ? "NW" : "India";
        var tempNumber = tempDetails == "India" ? "918956" : "0456";
        return new User
        {
            Name = dr.Field<string>("Name"),
            Age = dr.Field<int>("Age"),
            Details = tempDetails,
            Number = tempNumber,
        };
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: a semicolon (;) needs to be added right after the close bracket (}) of the return statement. Also, the collection object before the .Select statement must be converted to ToList() or AsEnumerable(). That is because IQuerable<T> or expression tree does not work with multi line statement body.

Comment: @Thomas.Benz You’re right about the semicolon, I missed that. As for queryables, my assumption is that this is a `DataTable` which [`Rows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rows?view=netframework-4.8) property is a collection, and not something you can run queries on.

Answer (score -1):

We can use lambda expression in this case :

```
var User = dsMappedDataFields.Tables[0].Rows.Cast <DataRow>().
Select(dr = > new User {
    Name = dr.Field<string>("Name"),
    Age = dr.Field<int>("Age"),
    Details = dr.Field<string>("Name") == "Rojer" ? "NW" : "India",
    Number = dr.Field<string>("Name") == "Rojer" ? 0456 : 918956,
}).ToList();
```

I tried the sample it works as you need.

Thanks,
Narasimha